# How do I access and modify phpmyadmin database from terminal?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I've been wanting to access the tables present in phpmyadmin by using select queries from the table. So far I've beeen unsuccessful. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Install the MySQL command line client, then type `mysql` to get started. For clarity, you have a *MySQL* database, not a phpMyAdmin one. phpMyAdmin is just a tool you use to access the database - it's like saying "I own a car key" when you mean "I own a car".

Comment: Could you please elaborate, what you mean by unsuccessful?

Comment: @ceejayoz PMA is more like a chauffeur. :)

Comment: @ceejayoz I'm fairly new to phpmyadmin and MySQL in general. I actually have a website hosted locally and uses the Mysql file as the backend. Which is being done through phpmyadmin. I want to access that sql file and modify it such that the changes are reflected in the website. Essentially the location of this database that phpmyadmin is modifying would also be useful.

Comment: You can use another MySQL managing tools like `HeidiSQL`, `Navicat for MySQL` etc..Also they can generate even advance queries for you.